# Reading Serial data from Arduino into Python

Tags: python, arduino, debian

I am new to coding.
I am trying to read serial data from an Arduino into a python script on a debian armf sbc. The point of the script is just to pass data from the arduino to the computer using the USB port. The Arduino is printing just an int: Serial.print(some-number-int) in its loop function.
The python code is here:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    x = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(x)
```

I heard that the decoding step used to not be a thing, but something changed and now you have to decode it or it spits out something like: "b'(int)\r\n"

This code works sometimes but is not stable. I will get errors when I run this code occasionally such as:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "read_usb_arduino.py", line 4, in <module> x = ser.readline().decode('utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

I was wondering if anyone knows a fix for this or a way to get by without decoding?

Thanks : D

Comment: What is the actual format of data over the serial link?

Comment: oh usb, forgot to put that in there.

Comment: So, what is the actual format of data over the serial link?

Comment: I'm not sure of the format. I am sending over and an integer like int x = 1; Serial.println(x)

Comment: So what do you expect in different cases? So `int x=1` should be `1\r\n` and `int x=5432` should be `5432\r\n`?

Comment: Yes. That is what I get without decoding the message. And I think the format might be ascii, the arduino website states "The serial port as human-readable ASCII text"

Comment: Ok, but if the arduino only sends ascii, then there should be no decode errors. However, serial is not infallible. Perhaps you should just catch the errors and discard the data.